# How to use ffmpeg to record video from SDP?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I have the following SDP Offer from Kurento Media Server. The offer is saved to the file **a.sdp** :

```
    v=0
    o=- 3831476180 3831476180 IN IP4 172.31.46.122
    s=Kurento Media Server
    c=IN IP4 172.31.46.122
    t=0 0
    m=audio 28460 RTP/AVPF 96 0 97
    a=setup:actpass
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2
    a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
    a=rtcp:28461
    a=sendrecv
    a=mid:audio0
    a=ssrc:1797155263 cname:user1913428254@host-e7ab0454
    m=video 18122 RTP/AVPF 102 103
    a=setup:actpass
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=rtpmap:102 VP8/90000
    a=rtpmap:103 H264/90000
    a=fmtp:103 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
    a=rtcp:18123
    a=sendrecv
    a=mid:video0
    a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:103 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:103 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm fir
    a=ssrc:2822275190 cname:user1913428254@host-e7ab0454
```

Then, I'm calling ffmpeg to record this flow to a file :

```
ffmpeg -max_delay 5000 -reorder_queue_size 16384 -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -re -i a.sdp -vcodec copy -acodec aac -y output.mp4
```

172.31.46.122 is the local ip adress and I'm running ffmpeg from the same machine as SDP offer. So ffmpeg has access to this ip adress.

I'm getting the error :

**bind failed: Address already in use.**

**a.sdp: Invalid data found when processing input**

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these or both:

1. `ffplay a.sdp -protocol_whitelist "file,udp,rtp"`
2. `ffmpeg -i a.sdp -protocol_whitelist "file,udp,rtp" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -y output.mp4`

Does it work if you reorder the parameters so that the input file is first?